# iMessage Alerts

Tags: messages

When using iMessage on a Mac and an iPod Touch, we get alert for every message in each device. That means, getting double alerted at a time.

For example, a new message comes and both Mac and iPod alerts. Are there any ways to get notified for once ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because it wouldn't be able to tell which device you are using and when. But what you could do is change your mac notifications to not receive any notifications for the messages app, however if you use messages.app for other messaging services, you probably won't get notifications for those either though. But once you read the message on any of your devices it should disappear, so if you were on your mac and read it, it would disappear from you iOS lock screen.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it will be good if Apple develops a system which can sync unread and read message information carefully over iCloud etc.

Comment: They have done that, but on OS X, the messages app still opens automatically when you get a message. So if you read the message on your iPhone, it would be shown as read on your Mac or iPad.